# Mac OS X - what's the best way of "communication" between an Cocoa app and a Java based app (daemon) running on the same box

Tags: cocoa, ipc

I have an app written in objective-c on Cocoa, having some UI. I am planning to write another Java app that could runs in the background and auto start (essentially a dameon). And then the Cocoa app will "communicate" with the Java app to start doing some tasks periodically or on demand. Is that doable? If so, what'll be the best way of communication between the two in terms of programming complexities? Socket? via File? Named pipe?

Comment: Is the communication one-way or bidirectional?

Comment: Hey Bryan, one-way from the Cocoa app to the Java app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's certainly doable.  There are a bunch of potential mechanisms, but they all come down to picking some interprocess communication mechanism.  But why do you want the java app as a daemon?  The sort of obvious thing is for your Cocoa app to just run the Java app.

If it turns out that for some reason -- say the java app has a lot of persistent state, or takes a long time to start up -- then the easiest method may be to use a named pipe, a/k/a a FIFO.  Once you create the FIFO, you can simply write to it from the UI process and read it, as a file, from Java.  This has the additional advantage that it provides a natural queue of events (which is what it's for, that's why it's called a FIFO.)

Comment: Charlie, thanks a lot! To have the Cocoa app to start/run the Java app seems to be a nice option to try. Especially to the scenario that I am tackling - the communication is one-way from the Cocoa app to the Java app. 

Considering one-way communication, would named pipe still a good choice? how about socket? I also want to lower down the programming cost.

Comment: Why not just start the Java app and put the information on the command line? That would make it easy to test the Java app too.

Answer (score 0):

How do you define "best"? Fastest? Simplest to set up? Transaction safe?

Perhaps the simplest way is to have your java app start an http or xmlrpc server on a separate thread. There are plenty of client and server libraries to help. As a side benefit, it makes the java app easier to test because you can use commandline tools like curl to simulate the cocoa app during development.

Comment: Hey Bryan, to me, the best defines to be the simplest and the fastest would be second to that. I will look into the option that you suggested - to start a http server on separate thread and to have the client (cocoa app) to work as client to talk to the http server. In the meanwhile, if you have some links on that topic, would you please mind to share them out? thanks!